# Check if row exists in db, and return boolean

Tags: java, mysql, row, exists

I have this funcion that takes a name and check in a database if a row exists with that name. However, i dont know how to determine if the row exists or not.

My code right now is

```
public static boolean rowExists(String player) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM currency WHERE name='"+player+"');";
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(player);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    
    ResultSet up = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    boolean nut = up.next();
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage("nut: " + nut + "  ");

    return nut;
}
```

nut is the boolean where true is the entry exists, and false it does not.
Currently nut always returns as true, whether the row exists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple queries are better:

```
SELECT 1 FROM currency WHERE name=%s LIMIT 1
```

This will return a single row of 1 if it exists, an 0 rows if it doesn't exist.

Also use prepared statement to avoid SQL injection.